# Is there a way to know when serverSideRender results have completed in Gutenberg? Like onChangeComplete?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I've seen onChangeComplete used in conjunction with onChange, but it doesn't seem to do anything in Gutenberg.

onChangeComplete seems to have a lot of issues or is severely misunderstood:
[#96](https://github.com/davidchin/react-input-range/issues/96) (price range related)
[#422](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color/issues/422) (color related)
[#516](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color/issues/516) (color related)